# Need help on visual fortran 6.6a I want to see a 100*80 array on a text file

Tags: arrays, fortran

Hi, I am trying to get a simple problem solved and see the whole array in 100*80 FORM, but as long as I tried I failed. I can do it for 5*5 array but not for 100*80 or bigger array.
Here is my code:

```
  PROGRAM Arr

REAL:: I,J,ITER,K
DIMENSION :: A(200,200)

A(1,1)=500
A(1,80)=300
A(100,1)=50
A(100,80)=40

READ(*,*) ITER

  DO K=1,ITER
  DO I=2,99
    DO J=2,89

 A(I,J)=(A(I+1,J)+A(I-1,J)+A(I,J+1)+A(I,J-1))/4

    END DO
  END DO
  END DO

 DO J=1,80
OPEN (UNIT=9, FILE='ARR.TXT', STATUS='REPLACE')

WRITE(9,*) (A(I,J),I=1,100)

 END DO

 END PROGRAM
```

---

Any comment will be helpful. Please tell me in detail.
Thanks.

Comment: Your caps lock key appears to be stuck.

Comment: Program in FORTRAN long enough and the caps lock key becomes permanent.

Comment: @Bort: In one of my Fortran projects with 15,000 lines, only 3% of the letters are upper case. My caps lock key is in fact rebound to Escape. Anyone who still writes FORTRAN in UPPERCASE is a masochist.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the simple list directed format, but specify it directly. Try

WRITE(9,'(200F12.5,x)') (A(I,J),I=1,100)

You can play with the numbers and see the difference or see some reference [Fortran Formats](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html).

Note, that the maximum record (line) length can be a problem you will not able to overcome.

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking on the button on the left.